# How can I make an Ext.Panel width override the width of its parent table layout?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the following code, if I define the top area as an **object literal**, then it overrides the default table width fine:

```
var top_area = {
    title:'Orders',
    width: 1210,
    colspan: 4,
    frame: true,
    border: true,
    header: true
};
```

[image]

Howver, if I define it as a **Ext.Panel**, then it erroneously takes on the default width of the table:

```
var top_area = new Ext.Panel({
    title:'Orders',
    width: 1210,
    colspan: 4,
    frame: true,
    border: true,
    header: true
});
```

[image]

**How do I get the Ext.Panel to override the default height of the table?**

Here's the full code:

```
var top_area = new Ext.Panel({
    title:'Orders',
    width: 1210,
    colspan: 4,
    frame: true,
    border: true,
    header: true
});

var table_wrapper2 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'table_wrapper2',
    baseCls: 'x-plain',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout:'table',
    layoutConfig: {columns:2},
    defaults: {
        frame:true,
        width:300,
        height: 300,
        style: 'margin: 0 10px 10px 0'
    },
    items:[{
            title:'Shopping Cart',
            width: 600,
            height: 390,
            colspan: 2
        },
        {
            title:'Invoice Address',
            width: 290,
            height: 200
        },{
            title:'Delivery Address',
            width: 300,
            height: 200
        }
    ]
})

var table_wrapper = new Ext.Panel({
    id:'table_wrapper',
    baseCls:'x-plain',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout:'table',
    layoutConfig: {columns:4},
    defaults: {
        frame:true,
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        style: 'margin: 10px 0 0 10px'
    },
    items:[top_area,{
            title:'Customer Information',
            width: 600,
            height: 600,
            colspan: 2
        },{
            frame: false,
            border: false,
            width: 600,
            height: 600,
            colspan: 2,
            items: [ table_wrapper2 ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Amol below is right, that solves you issue. Maybe it's also good to look at the vbox and hbox layouts, I like those much better than the table layouts, no spanning and stuff required.

Comment: +1 to Rob. I too prefer using vbox & hbox in conjuction than using the table layout to achieve the same placement. My answer below is with an assumption that you want to make your existing code work and should technically solve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the default width since you are overriding it for all the items anyway.

```
defaults: {
    frame:true,
    width: 300, //<-- remove this
    height: 300,
    style: 'margin: 10px 0 0 10px'
},
```